# custom splashscreen not showing with ionic and phonegap build (3.5.0)

Tags: splash-screen, phonegap-build, ionic-framework

I'm referring to phonegap doc here:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/configuring_icons_and_splash.md.html
yet can't have the splashscreen to show after building ( build via phonegap build service, not locally )

relevant ( I suppose ) config.xml lines:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:splash src="splash.png" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

splash.png is in the root, as is config.xml, is a 480x800 PNG (32-bit color)

I'm building with phonegap 3.5.0 selected; pulling from the git for the ionic project ( so no local 'platforms' dir in the way, since it's in ionic .gitignore.

I also tried the

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
```

options to no result ('res/screen... dirs also starting from the root where config resides')

I have made no specific splash show/hide code in the app, is this mandatory ? I just want the splash to show for a fixed bunch of seconds...

Answer (score -1):

My advice is twofold:

First, use PGB 3.6.3. Not only is 3.5 outdated, it also has a security flaw in Android that means apps will be removed from the Past Store.

Second (re: your problem). Go back to basics - follow the PGB docs on splash screens in the simplest way possible.

I don't know what the issue, it looks OK to me, but there are a few preferences you have that I don't use and it works fine for me. I'd expand more but I'm on a mobile. I'll check it out in detail later.